# How to adjust the screen size in Processing to use for Html5?

Tags: html, screen, processing

I would like to ask how can I adjust the screen size in Processing to use for Html5?

I tried to write **size( displayWidth * 0.80, displayHeight  * 0.80)** to have the %80.

The sketch alone works fine but it doesn't work when I insert it in a web page Html5. I'm using Processing.js in htlm5 web page.

Thanks a lot!

This is my Html page:

```
<html>
<body >
<script src="my_project/processing.js"></script> 
<canvas data-processing-sources="my_project/foo/foo.pde"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

This page is supposed to display my Processing foo.pde sketch

This is my foo.pde sketch:

```
void setup()
{
   //this works if I launch my sketch alone,
   //but it doesnt work when it is visualised in a web page!
   size( int(displayWidth * 0.80), int(displayHeight * 0.80));

   //if I use
   //size(100, 100)
   //this is displayed correctly in my html page!
}

void draw()
{
   ellipse(250,250,70,70);
}
```

Comment: Try showing us the code you're using? Snippets of both your processing code AND the html.

Comment: I have already added the code, thanks :)